# Conditional formatting of TRUE / FALSE values in an Excel 2010 range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I have a range containing formulas that evaluate to TRUE or FALSE.

How would one apply conditional formatting to this range, so that TRUE cells are Green, and FALSE cells are RED?

Comment: Ya I just went through all my old questions to see if I could do that, and all of them are basically still outstanding or indeterminate.

Comment: The problem with doing "Cell value equal to" is that empty cells compare equal to FALSE somehow and thus get highlighted red for me.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

1. Select your cells.
2. Home Tab -> Format Group -> Conditional Formatting -> New Style:
   [image: True Values]
3. Repeat step 2 with this:
   [image: False Values]

Comment: This is for Mac, but the windows version is extremely similar, just slight modification.

Comment: I didn't have a Windows ready :S.

Comment: @Microsoft: How about a preset for this?

Comment: doesn't this answer depend on the locale, because it relies on the text presentation of boolean values? I mean what if I have a boolean cell in an Excel-file created by my Korean colleagues? or if I use a Russian locale in my Excel? will the formatting disappear?

Answer (score 2):

For Windows version.
Microsoft 365 Excel (Version 2004(Build 12730.20270)
*Note the version is not the year - this is the 365 version in year 2020

You need to create 2 rules (one for each colour)
Go to

1. Home Tab -> Styles Group -> Conditional formatting -> Manage rules
   *Alternatively just type Conditional formatting in the search bar at the top
2. New rule
3. Rule type -> Format only cells that contain
   Cell Value -> Equal to -> {your value in this case True} =TRUE
   And select the format, then okay

[image]

4. this will take you back to manage rules where you now have one rule. Now do steps 2-4 again but for the False value

[image]

Now you should have 2 rules in your manage rules window

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The usual Conditional Formatting rule of **"Equal To" was not working for me** when using "true"/"false"

I found that the **"Text that Contains" option worked** instead:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What if I want to change the color of a entire row?