# How to change row color based on a single cell's value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conditional formatting of TRUE / FALSE values in an Excel 2010 range](https://superuser.com/questions/327066/conditional-formatting-of-true-false-values-in-an-excel-2010-range)

I have a spreadsheet where I have cell within a row that will contain specific text via data validation. So for instance a cell could contain the text "Due in 7 Days", "Past Due", or "Closed".

I want the row color to change depending on the text that appears in the cell. So if the text "Past Due" appears in the cell I want that entire row to turn red, if "Due In 7 Days" appears the row should turn yellow, and if "Closed" the row would turn gray.

How can I do that?

Comment: this isn't an exact duplicate of the linked T/F question, though they involve a solution using the same feature.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with formula-based conditional formatting.

1. Select the cells you want to apply the formatting to.
2. On the **Home** tab, click on "Conditional formatting" → "Manage rules..."
3. Click "New Rule..."
4. Select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
5. In the formula field, enter the following:
   `=SEARCH("Due in", $C1) > 0`
   Instead of `C1`, use the cell that contains the texts you want to check. But note the `$` sign in front of it - that tells Excel to keep the column the same as it expands the formula across the row. That's the trick to applying formatting to an entire row based on a single cell's value.
6. Click "Format..."
7. Select the colour you want on the **Font** tab (if you meant text colour) or the **Fill** tab (if you meant background colour), as well as any other formatting options you want
8. Click **OK** twice
9. Once back in the Rules Manager, click **Apply** to see the formatting in effect, and make sure it's how you wanted
10. Repeat steps 3-8 for the other texts you want to check for, each time selecting the proper colours
11. Click **OK** or **Close** to exit the Rules Manager

That should do it.

Comment: +1, nice use of SEARCH function.  I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: +1 Just a note, on office 2007 you can't put = in the formulea field. So just put something like SEARCH("Due in", $C1) > 0

Comment: Nevermind my last command. The actual problem was in french its RECHERCHE("Due in"; $C1) > 0

Answer (score 2):

Use a conditional format with a formula like `=INDIRECT("C"&ROW())="Past Due"` and set the background color to red. Add similar rules for the other formats you want to apply. Replace `"C"` with the actual column holding the values you want to check.