# Change color of row according to column value (by regex)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, regex, openoffice-calc

I'm quite new to `excel` so this could be dumb question. I need to change color for those rows which has suffix `.com` in their second column. I use `OpenOffice` but I can change it using `Microsoft Excel` too.

So the thing I want is:

**Change a color of the row which second column value match this regex: "*.*/.com"** <= This `regex` may not be correct.

Comment: Why not conditional or instr http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instr.php ... It will probably be easier to maintain

Comment: @Dave I don't care if it is a regex, it could be instr but I don't know how to use it since I'm very new in excel.

Comment: Did you try conditional formatting? There are many tutorials and you may have more luck, unless you specifically want to learn VBa? The link I have shows how to use it, also see http://superuser.com/questions/801609/how-do-i-add-vba-in-ms-office

Comment: Your idea of changing the colour has potential issues with VBa. After you've changed the colour, it doesn't just change back! This means you've changed the rows with .com in... You then insert a new row and run the code again, unless you tell it too, it won't chnage the highlighted colours back. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/45670/how-to-highlight-a-row-in-excel-using-conditional-formatting/

Comment: Is ".com" the ending of a cell, or could it be in the middle too?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Format -> Conditional Formatting -> Manage` and click Add.

In the first two drop-down lists, choose "Cell value is" and "Ends with".  In the box, enter `".com"` in quotes.  At the bottom of the dialog, specify `B1:B1000` for the Cell Range.

In the Apply Style drop-down, select `New Style...`  Go to the Background tab and choose a bright color, for example yellow.  Then press OK.

Now if a cell in the second column contains "google.com", then it will be highlighted.  If it gets changed to something else, for example "redcross.org", then it will no longer be highlighted.

Documentation is at https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Conditional_Formatting.

Comment: can't speak for the OP, but I believe the request was for a whole row - can that be applied to a whole row?

Comment: Coloring more cells is also possible.  See  http://superuser.com/questions/598871/how-to-color-rows-based-on-cell-value-in-open-libre-office?rq=1.