# Conditonal formatting (color scale) based on custom formula in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, libreoffice-calc

Libre Office allows applying a color scale to cells by selecting `Format -> Conditional -> Color scale`. The middle dropdown is "Percentile" by default, but it is possible to pick "Formula". However, how do you enter the formula? What is the variable representing the current cell? This doesn't seem documented anywhere in the help files.

For example, I have 165 values in column G ranging from 0.790 to 5243.616. If I just do the regular formatting on these, it is not very useful, as the small values all get colored red. Instead, I would like to apply color based on the *logarithm* of these values. So for each `Gi`, the color should be assigned according to `=LOG(Gi)`, and also the min/max should be determined with something like `min(log(G:G))`.

How do I write this formula?

Comment: If that were possible it would be a burden. Perhaps insert a column to compute Log and put a few rows at the top for Min,Avg,Max Std Dev values of an array as a summary for any column above the array.  Did you try https://superuser.com/questions/598871/how-to-color-rows-based-on-cell-value-in-openoffice-and-libreoffice ?  THen have the log values in order  -1,0,1,2,3,4,5 for your thresholds outside column

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Isn't the point of the "Formula" option that it lets you use any arbitrary formula? Why do you say it's a burden?