# Conditionally format entire row based on a cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I know this has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23276769/conditional-formatting-entire-row-if-any-cell-contains-the-specified-text) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22339210/using-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-a-row-if-the-date-in-the-column-f-equa), but I must be missing something.  I want to put a border above all rows that contain "Monday".

[image]

The formula is `=$B$3="*Monday*"`

I thought it might be because the value of the cell is actually "4/18/2016" but I manually changed it to "Monday" and the rule still didn't fire.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/479984/116196

Comment: =$B$3="Monday" write the formula without stars just quotes

Answer (score 2):

Having the formula pointing on $B$3 will always be true or false, if $B$3 is Monday or not. You need to make the row a relativ reference, ie the formula should be something like `=IF($B3="Monday";TRUE;FALSE)`.

The omitted $ in front of the row will make this formula look into the first column in every row, thus making a border around all mondays.

In order to improve the formula and assuming that you have a date value in your date column, I would recommend to use the function `WEEKDAY()` and to check for the numeric value of the weekday (see [Microsoft Help](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WEEKDAY-function-60e44483-2ed1-439f-8bd0-e404c190949a)).

Comment: FWIW When using conditional formatting it is not needed to have the IF() wrapper that returns TRUE/FALSE.  Simply `$B3="Monday"` will do as it will return the needed TRUE/FALSE.  But your explanation is well done.

Comment: This is absolutely true, but I met many people, who were not able to understand the boolean implication of the short version, which is why I forced myself to always write the "long version". :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `WEEKDAY()` function.

Syntax: `WEEKDAY(serial_number,[return_type])`

Use this formula in your conditional format, assuming column A contains your dates.

```
=WEEKDAY(A1,2)=1
```

With the return type of `2`, it starts the week with Monday being the 1st day. So the formula will identify the weekdays that are equal to 1 then format them with your rule.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was two-fold.  I fixed the formula to be `=$B3="Monday"`. I also had to create an additional column with the formula of `=TEXT(C3,"dddd")` so that the value was actually "Monday".  As it was before, the content of the cell being "2016/4/18", it was only displaying Monday due to the cell format.  This never triggered the condition.

Here is the result with Monday replaced by Saturday and Sunday.

[image]

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out. For future reference, the only thing I want to point out is that your question does not say anything about needing to add a column and convert the date to a text day. Those types of details are important to get specific helpful answers. Please be more specific in future questions.

Comment: That was the *answer*.  I didn't know I needed to do that when I asked the question.

Comment: Updated my answer, maybe it's more clear now?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Just appeared to be additional information after the fact. Well done.